# PHP Array reference replacement

Tags: php

I have following code

```
public function index() {
    $a = 2;
    $b = 8;

    $arr[] = $a;
    $arr[] = &$a;
    $arr[] = $a;

    $this->dmp($arr);

    $arr[1] = $b;

    $this->dmp($arr);

    $a++;
    $b++;

    $this->dmp($arr);
}

private function dmp($val) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($val);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

which gives me following result

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
int(2)
[1]=>
&int(2)
[2]=>
int(2)
}
array(3) {
[0]=>
int(2)
[1]=>
&int(8)
[2]=>
int(2)
}
array(3) {
[0]=>
int(2)
[1]=>
&int(9)
[2]=>
int(2)
}
```

Q: Why the value on index 1 is not replaced with value of $b variable, but there is still the reference? The reference remains even after calling $arr[1] = $b; without the appersand?

Comment: It is replaced, first with 8 then with 9.

Comment: @u_mulder yes, but I am calling $arr[1] = $b; but there is still a reference in the array. I am not calling $arr[1] = &$b; to set new reference on the index.

Comment: `echo $a;` and you will see.

Comment: maybe I am unable to clearly specify my question due to my bad english, but I am wondering, why there is still the reference on index 1 in the array after I replace it with calling $arr[1] = $b; (which is asigment of value, not a reference, right?)

Comment: When you assign a reference it creates a link between the two and so when you make another assignment it also assigns to the referenced variable. That's why I said echo `$a` you will see it changes to 8 and then 9.  To break the reference use `unset`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ok, thank you, but why the reference is changed with calling $arr[1] = $b; and I dont need to call $arr[1] = &$b;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple explanation:

```
$arr[0] = $a; // Index 0 holds the same value as $a which is 2
$arr[1] = &$a; // Index 1 holds a reference to variable $a
$arr[2] = $a;  // Index 2 holds the same value as $a which is 2
```

You then instruct the code to change the value of the variable referenced by index 1, to hold the same value as `$b` which is `8`.

```
$arr[1] = $b; // Index 1 references variable $a so $a will become 8
```

If you do `var_dump($a)` now, you will see that `$a` is `8`.

You then increment both `$a` and `$b`, which at this point have the same value. They both will now have the value `9`

The contents of the array at the end are the same as initially specified. The only difference is that the variable which is referenced by element with index 1 has now a different value.

```
$arr[0] = 2; // Index 0 holds the value 2
$arr[1] = &$a; // Index 1 holds a reference to variable $a which has a value 9 now
$arr[2] = 2;  // Index 2 holds the value 2
```

Comment: thx for your explanation. I am just confused, why if I call $arr[1] = $b; the index 1 of the array doesnt become just value of $b, If I would like to keep reference on another variable I would expect to call $arr[1] = &$b;

Comment: @Crusty The element with index 1 just points to variable `$a`, so when you do `$arr[1] = $b;` it essentially means `$a = $b`;

Comment: When you do `$arr[1] = &$b;` you are telling PHP that element with index 1 now points to another variable. That index will now point to the same memory location as variable `$b` does.

Comment: If you can't wrap your head around references think about it as an alias. `$arr[1] = &$a` means that `$arr[1]` is an alias of `$a`. The name of the variable is different, but the memory location is the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign by reference it creates a *link* between the two, they are pointing to the same result.  So when you make another assignment it also assigns to the referenced variable. If you inspect `$a` you will see it changes to 8 and then 9. To break the reference use `unset()`.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4FvhH)

This `$arr[] = &$a;` says make `$arr[1]` point to the same data as `$a`.

This `$arr[1] = $b;` says assign the value of `$b` to `$arr[1]`, which is 8, and `$a` is linked to `$arr[1]` so `$a` is 8 as well.

Check [What References Do](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

Comment: thx for your explanation. I am just confused, why I dont need to call $arr[1] = &$b; to change referenced variable

Comment: It doesn't change the reference variable,`$arr[1]` is still a reference to`$a`.  When you assign `$b` it just assigns the value of `$b` which is 8.